# How to connect azure function from angularjs 1.6

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

How to connect and manage azure function authentication and authorization

Comment: You should do some initial effort and research and post a specific question with steps that you've tried, screenshots, code and detailed issues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp

I got the solution and did some minor fixes in the library and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make HTTP-triggered function, connect the same way as to any other HTTP endpoint. There is nothing specific to Angular in connecting to Functions.

For auth see [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview).